# How to solve this Pyspark Code Block using Regexp

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have this CSV file

[image]

but when I am running my notebook regex shows some error

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

path="dbfs:/FileStore/df/test.csv"
dff = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option('multiline', 'true').option('encoding', 'UTF-8').option("delimiter", "‡‡,‡‡").csv(path)

dff.show(truncate=False)
#dffs_headers = dff.dtypes

for i in dffs_headers:
  columnLabel = i[0]
  print(columnLabel)
  newColumnLabel = columnLabel.replace('‡‡','').replace('‡‡','')
  
  dff=dff.withColumn(newColumnLabel,regexp_replace(columnLabel,'^\\‡‡|\\‡‡$','')).drop(newColumnLabel)
  
  if columnLabel != newColumnLabel:
    dff = dff.drop(columnLabel)
    dff.show(truncate=False)
```

As and a result I am getting this

[image]

Can anyone improvise this code, it will be a great help.

Expected output is

`|��123456��,��Version2��,��All questions have been answered accurately and the guidance in the questionnaire was understood and followed��,��2010-12-16 00:01:48.020000000��|`

But I am getting

`��Id��,��Version��,��Questionnaire��,��Date��`

Second column is showing Truncated value

Comment: whats the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working asnwer

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

path="dbfs:/FileStore/df/test.csv"
dff = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option('multiline', 'true').option('encoding', 'UTF-8').option("delimiter", "‡‡,‡‡").csv(path)

#dffs_headers = dff.dtypes

for i in dffs_headers:
  columnLabel = i[0]
  newColumnLabel = columnLabel.replace('‡‡','').replace('‡‡','')
  
  dff=dff.withColumn(newColumnLabel,regexp_replace(columnLabel,'^\\‡‡|\\‡‡$',''))
  
  if columnLabel != newColumnLabel:
    dff = dff.drop(columnLabel)
  dff.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import the libraries you want to use first, to use them. The below code in a cell before the regexp_replace call should fix this issue

`from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace`

Comment: Can you please see this I have edited question again your import function was right but still not getting required request